# Qt QMYSQL "Driver not loaded" on Windows

Tags: c++, mysql, windows, qt, dll

While trying to connect to a mysql Database i'm getting the following Error: Driver not loaded.

I've created an Installer with all the needed DLL Files (libmysql.dll, plugins/qsqlmysql.dll, QT5Sql etc.). While testing the program in a freshly installed windows 10 VM all worked fine, but on a different PC, also with windows 10, i'm getting the driver not loaded error.

I've used depends.exe to check that all needed DLL's are there and they are.

[image]

According to QSqlDatabase::drivers() there are no database drivers available.

Are there any possibilities to get a more useful error description?

Comment: You should install MySQL to "different PC"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Problem was releted to the anti virus software that was silently blocking the qsqlmysql.dll. The anti virus software did log the file as an virus but didn't ever show a info message.

Answer (score 2):

It seems your `qsqlmysql.dll` which is your sql plugin is in the same folder as your application while it should be in the sqldrivers folder.

What you probably need to do :

- move `qsqlmysql.dll` and `libmysql-dll` (and dependencies) to the plugins subfolder
- try to restart, you might want to debug with library path that Qt uses for loading.

If this fixes the issue, then fix your installer.

You might want to look at http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/deployment-plugins.html for deploying plugins

Comment: The qsqlmysql.dll is already inside the sqldrivers folder, the file inside the main folder is just a copy to test if it makes a difference. I should deleted it before i've created the screenshot, sorry!

Comment: Have you tried using depends to on the plugin to be sure it can be loaded ? Just to be sure the actual mysql dll you embedded is enough. The usual methods of investigation are usually traces (debug messages) to see what it's trying to load and when and when it's failing... Without more, hard to provide an accurate input

Comment: Yes i've tried that, thank you very much for your effort!! I've found the answer myself.